# Basic C / C++ explanation

Tags: c++, c

I wanted to check the performances of an algorithm in computer vision and I ended up with this basic piece of code just to check what loop was the fastest. But I do not have any explanation on the result. I generally get a result showing  that the double for loop is 3 times faster that the simple loop. And if I switch the two loops, I get the same result, which means that the second one is always optimized ... So what kind of optimization does the compiler make ?

I am sorry I know this must be a silly question ...

```
ulong k = 0;
auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
for( uint i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i )
{
    k++;
}
auto diff = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;
auto t1 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(diff);

k = 0;
start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
for( uint i = 0; i < 1000; ++i )
{
    for( uint j = 0; j < 1000; ++j )
    {
        k++;
    }
}
diff = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;
auto t2 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(diff);

CL_PRINT( "Simple: ", t1.count() );
CL_PRINT( "Double: ", t2.count() );
```

And if I switched the two loops, I get the same result, which means that the second one is always optimized ...

Note that `CL_PRINT` is just a macro for debug purposes.
Also note that I compile the code with those options: `-O3 -msse4.1`

Comment: Did you read the generated code to see that all the loops "survived" intact? At `-O3` I wouldn't be surprised if the compiler notices that the value of `k` is never used and re-structured the code significantly.

Comment: lol "re-structured ... significant" is an awesome euphemism for "eliminates the dead code"

Comment: No I did not, but I will. I did not know that the compiler could optimize that much ... So the compiler does optimize it, but why is the second loop always faster ? It is the same "dead code" so it should optimize it in both cases, no ?

Comment: Yes, this why it is actually allowed to print something for this code: for(;;); printf("hello"); - the forever loop has no side effects, so the compiler may reorder it or remove it completely. Try making your k volatile, so this is not allowed.

Comment: I did, and I get a few millisecond, which is normal since I have three operations on a 3Ghz processor. But statically the second one is still faster ... I will check the different generated codes with the different options to have a deeper understanding on why this is the case.

Comment: This is a reasonable question, I don't get the downvotes. The only reason a compiler is allowed to optimise away code is if it can prove that the results could not have any "visible effect" (elapsed time does not count), and the two loops are *identical* with respect to that criterion. So I suspect the answer is unreasonable: you have hit a spot where the optimisation heuristics behave stupidly.  I suspect that in particular the compiler does not "realise" that the `k = 0;` following the first loop means that this calculation is not needed.

Comment: Really interesting answer (I should have stated that I use GCC 4.7.3). Shall we consider this as the answer for the question ?

Comment: @unwind The second test with the double loop remains faster even if you use the value of k (for example, print it after both tests). http://ideone.com/oze4V7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer here is that the exact timing varies. When I run [this code](http://ideone.com/oze4V7) on my machine, it comes up with 1000 for the first loop sometimes, and 1000 for the second loop at other times. It's just "luck" when the timer ticks over. If you have a more accurate timer, it may show differences based on how long it takes to read the timer, or some such.

```
$ ./a.out
k = 1000000
k = 1000000
Simple: 0
Double: 1000
$ ./a.out
k = 1000000
k = 1000000
Simple: 1000
Double: 0
$ ./a.out
k = 1000000
k = 1000000
Simple: 1000
Double: 0
$ ./a.out
k = 1000000
k = 1000000
Simple: 1000
Double: 0
```

It is easy to see that BOTH loops are optimized out:

```
main:
.LFB1474:
.cfi_startproc
pushq   %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
.cfi_offset 6, -16
pushq   %rbx
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 24
.cfi_offset 3, -24
subq    $8, %rsp
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
call    _ZNSt6chrono12system_clock3nowEv
movq    %rax, %rbx
call    _ZNSt6chrono12system_clock3nowEv
movl    $.LC0, %esi
**subq  %rbx, %rax**
movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
imulq   $1000, %rax, %rbp
call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc
**movl  $1000000, %esi**
movq    %rax, %rdi
call    _ZNSo9_M_insertImEERSoT_
movq    %rax, %rdi
call    _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
call    _ZNSt6chrono12system_clock3nowEv
movq    %rax, %rbx
call    _ZNSt6chrono12system_clock3nowEv
movl    $.LC0, %esi
**subq  %rbx, %rax**
movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
imulq   $1000, %rax, %rbx
call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc
**movl  $1000000, %esi**
movq    %rax, %rdi
call    _ZNSo9_M_insertImEERSoT_
movq    %rax, %rdi
call    _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
movl    $.LC1, %esi
movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc
movq    %rbp, %rsi
movq    %rax, %rdi
call    _ZNSo9_M_insertIlEERSoT_
movq    %rax, %rdi
call    _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
movl    $.LC2, %esi
movl    $_ZSt4cout, %edi
call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc
movq    %rbx, %rsi
movq    %rax, %rdi
call    _ZNSo9_M_insertIlEERSoT_
movq    %rax, %rdi
call    _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
addq    $8, %rsp
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 24
xorl    %eax, %eax
popq    %rbx
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
popq    %rbp
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
ret
```

You can clearly see the constants for K being inserted into the stream as constants, and the time for "before" and "after" is taken and then subtracted without (much) code in between. (The "interesting" bits are marked with `** ... **` - it doesn't make it bold in code of course)